# Comparar Linha Atual com a Anterior

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou querendo em uma coluna "Teste" definir o valor "S" para somente na primeira linha de um determinado "código" e todas as demais definir o valor "N" e assim sucessivamente para todos os outros códigos em um SELECT, estou utilizando o SQL SERVER.

```
ID COD VLR    DATA      TESTE
01 123 100 "06/09/2015"   S
04 123 400 "03/09/2015"   N
05 123 500 "02/09/2015"   N
02 456 200 "05/09/2015"   S
03 456 300 "04/09/2015"   N
06 789 600 "01/09/2015"   S
```

Obs: verifiquei que tem as funções LAG e LEAD, porém não consegui fazer isso usando elas.

Desde já, agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi. Você quer fazer um `update` onde todas as linhas (exceto a primeira) fiquem com o valor da coluna *teste* ao contrário do valor da primeira linha?

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Não seria um Update, seria em um Select mesmo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa usando apenas o ROW_NUMBER para aqueles que ainda estão a usar o SQL Server 2008.

Para a seguinte tabela

```
CREATE TABLE Teste(id CHAR(02), cod INT, valor INT, data DATE);
INSERT INTO Teste(id, cod, valor, data) VALUES
('01', 123, 100, '2015-09-06'),
('04', 123, 400, '2015-09-03'),
('05', 123, 500, '2015-09-02'),
('02', 456, 200, '2015-09-05'),
('03', 456, 300, '2015-09-04'),
('06', 789, 600, '2015-09-01');
```

A instrução seguinte

```
SELECT id,
       cod,
       valor,
       data,
       CASE 
          WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cod ORDER BY id) = 1 THEN 'S'
          ELSE 'N'
       END AS Teste
FROM   Teste
ORDER BY 2, 1, 3
```

Irá gerar o seguinte output

```
id  cod  valor      data        Teste
01  123  100        2015-09-06  S
04  123  400        2015-09-03  N
05  123  500        2015-09-02  N
02  456  200        2015-09-05  S
03  456  300        2015-09-04  N
06  789  600        2015-09-01  S
```

Para quem usa SQL Server 2012 (ou mais recente) pode usar a função LAG para obter o mesmo output. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT id,
       cod,
       valor,
       data,
       LAG('N', 1, 'S') OVER (PARTITION BY cod ORDER BY id) Teste
FROM   Teste
ORDER BY 2, 1, 3;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1441/2)

Comment: muito obrigado, era exatamente isso que eu estava precisando.