# Identificar a mudança de registro em uma tabela temporal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou trabalhando em uma tabela que mantem o histórico de algumas pessoas, e preciso identificar e exibir as linhas que tenham sofrido alguma modificação em uma determinada coluna.

Ver exemplo:

```
--Tabela HistSituacaoPessoa
id | nome   | situacao | data
999| Fulano | Ativo    | 2017-12-08 23:59:06.947
999| Fulano | Ativo    | 2017-12-09 23:59:06.947
999| Fulano | Inativo  | 2017-12-10 23:59:06.947
999| Fulano | Inativo  | 2017-12-11 23:59:06.947
999| Fulano | Inativo  | 2017-12-12 23:59:06.947
999| Fulano | Cobranca | 2017-12-13 23:59:06.947
999| Fulano | Ativo    | 2017-12-14 23:59:06.947
999| Fulano | Ativo    | 2017-12-14 23:59:06.947
999| Fulano | Inativo  | 2017-12-15 23:59:06.947
```

Eu preciso saber a linha que ouve a modificação, no primeiro caso mostra a linha que tem Ativo, depois deve me mostrar a linha que tem Inativo, a próxima que quero saber é a linha que aparece a cobrança.
Com o exemplo da tabela acima os dados a serem exibido devem ser os seguintes:

```
 --Valores que devem ser exibidos baseado na tabela acima
     999| Fulano | Ativo    | 2017-12-08 23:59:06.947 
     999| Fulano | Inativo  | 2017-12-10 23:59:06.947
     999| Fulano | Cobranca | 2017-12-13 23:59:06.947
     999| Fulano | Ativo    | 2017-12-14 23:59:06.947
     999| Fulano | Inativo  | 2017-12-15 23:59:06.947
```

Quero saber quais as datas que teve alteração na situação de uma pessoa.
Qual a maneira que posso fazer a consulta?

Comment: Não consegui entender o que você quer! O que foi alterado nas linhas que o `SELECT` deve retornar? A situação? E se você armazenar a data da ultima consulta em algum lugar e fazer esse `SELECT` se baseando na data armazenada?

Comment: Editei. O que quero de retorno é saber as datas que uma pessoa teve alteração na situação. Saber que se Fuluna estava ativo no dia 10 e no dia 12 ele ficou inativo. Claro que retornando todas as colunas da consulta.

Comment: Pelo que entendi ele quer saber o que mudou em uma tabela e quem mudou e quando. Essencialmente seria um log? Bom, nessa caso eu imagino criar uma tabela de histórico, e preencher ela com triguers ou procs conforme a tabela principal vai mudando

Comment: @JoeTorres Eu considero como histórico, pois a tabela está sendo atualizada todo os dias durante o ano.

Comment: Entendi. Bom vc pode fazer algo como isso https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server em que existe uam replicação de dados. Ele vai pegar toda e qualquer alteração que vc fizer. Ou se vc quiser só cosisa especificas, coloqueu ma trigger na tabela que salve em outra tabela quais alterações foram feitas. ou se o acesos a essa tabela for feito só por procedures, salvar nessas tabela de histórico as alterações pertinentes. DE qualquer maneira, é um trabalhindo razoável, mas não impossivel.

Comment: Cara não vou colocar como resposta porque não tenho certeza se vai funcionar no seu caso, mas tenta com esse `SELECT`:

Comment: `SELECT id, nome, situacao, DATA FROM HistSituacaoPessoa
GROUP BY nome
ORDER BY DATA DESC`

Comment: @RobertodeCampos Muito obrigado! Mas encontrei outra solução.

Comment: @JoeTorres Obrigado! Encontrei a solução.

Comment: Porque me dar negativo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esse pergunta a solução é verificar a linha atual com a linha anterior, dessa forma tem a função LAG para as versões a partir da SQL Server 2012.

Sendo assim a solução:

```
SELECT id,
       nome,
       LAG('N',1,'S') OVER (PARTITION BY situcao ORDER BY id) as teste,
       data
FROM HistSituacaoPessoa
```

Mais informação [AQUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87308/comparar-linha-atual-com-a-anterior) e [AQUI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14317/como-usar-lead-e-lag-usando-uma-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o)